# How to know job overrunning in Control-M

Tags: server, monitoring, scheduling, control-m

If a job which should take  max 2 hours to execute  but it takes more than it ,how should i know that ? What is color of that job ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot distinguish based on the color, i.e, theres no separate color for that. The job will just be in yellow color.

You can make use of BIM (Batch Impact Manager), which does exactly what you need. It notifies you when a job that is supposed to run in 2 hours does not do so.

Answer (score 0):

In addition you can also add a message alert if it takes longer than expected. For example -

[image]